# Select First Row in UITableViewController on load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I saw multiple threads on selecting the first row by default in a UITableViewController with a NavigationController, and I used some of the code I found via some of the communities answers, but it's still not working for me.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .middle)
}
```

It just highlights any row I put as the indexPath, but it doesn't actually go to the view associated with that indexPath. I feel like it's connected right though, because when I do actually click the row it goes to the view. Am I missing a step here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a
>   tableView(*:willSelectRowAt:) or tableView(*:didSelectRowAt:) message,
>   nor does it send UITableViewSelectionDidChange notifications to
>   observers.

You must call `UITableview`'s delegate `didSelectRowAt` method.

Comment: You should not call the delegate method yourself. There should be a separate method that does the actual navigation. Then the delegate method should call that separate method. And the separate method can also be called from `viewDidAppear`.